# Time Complexity?

Tags: c, linked-list, time-complexity, singly-linked-list

Problem was to find the intersection of 2 sorted linked lists and store the common elements in the third list.

My approach was to make temporary pointers `temp1` and `temp2` initializing both to `head1` (head of list 1) and `head2` (head of list 2) respectively.And then traversing both lists and comparing elements and shifting `temp1` and `temp2` accordingly.The code works fine.

Test case:
First linked list=> 1->2->3->4->6 
Second linked list be 2->4->6->8, then  function should create and return a third list as 2->4->6.

But I am confused about what is the time complexity: **O(m+n)** or **O(min(m,n))**? (m,n are number of elements in list 1 and list 2).

My Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

/* Link list node */
struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
};
void append(struct Node** head_ref, int new_data)
{
    /* 1. allocate node */
    struct Node* new_node = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    struct Node *last = *head_ref;  /* used in step 5*/

    /* 2. put in the data  */
    new_node->data  = new_data;

    /* 3. This new node is going to be the last node, so make next 
          of it as NULL*/
    new_node->next = NULL;

    /* 4. If the Linked List is empty, then make the new node as head */
    if (*head_ref == NULL)
    {
       *head_ref = new_node;
       return;
    }  

    /* 5. Else traverse till the last node */
    while (last->next != NULL)
        last = last->next;

    /* 6. Change the next of last node */
    last->next = new_node;
    return;    
}

struct Node* sortedIntersect(struct Node* head1,struct Node*head2)
{
    struct Node*head3=NULL;
    struct Node*temp1=head1;
    struct Node*temp2=head2;
    while(temp1!=NULL&&temp2!=NULL)
    {
        if(temp1->data<temp2->data)
        {if(temp1->next!=NULL)
            temp1=temp1->next;
            else
            break;
        } 
        else if(temp1->data>temp2->data)
        {
            if(temp2->next!=NULL)
            temp2=temp2->next;
            else{
                break;
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            append(&head3,temp1->data);
            temp1=temp1->next;
            temp2=temp2->next;
        }
    }
    return head3;
}


/* Function to insert a node at the beginging of the linked list */
void push(struct Node** head_ref, int new_data)
{
    /* allocate node */
    struct Node* new_node = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    /* put in the data */
    new_node->data = new_data;

    /* link the old list off the new node */
    new_node->next = (*head_ref);

    /* move the head to point to the new node */
    (*head_ref) = new_node;
}

/* Function to print nodes in a given linked list */
void printList(struct Node *node)
{
    while (node != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", node->data);
        node = node->next;
    }
}


int main()
{
    /* Start with the empty lists */
    struct Node* a = NULL;
    struct Node* b = NULL;
    struct Node *intersect = NULL;

    /* Let us create the first sorted linked list to test the functions
    Created linked list will be 1->2->3->4->5->6 */
    push(&a, 6);
    push(&a, 5);
    push(&a, 4);
    push(&a, 3);
    push(&a, 2);
    push(&a, 1);

    /* Let us create the second sorted linked list
    Created linked list will be 2->4->6->8 */
    push(&b, 8);
    push(&b, 6);
    push(&b, 4);
    push(&b, 2);

    /* Find the intersection two linked lists */
    intersect = sortedIntersect(a, b);

    printf("\n Linked list containing common items of a & b \n ");
    printList(intersect);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem that *can be solved* in `O(m+n)`.

However, this solution is not `O(m+n)`. Each element you add in the method `intersectSorted` is added with the method `append`, which traverses the whole current output list.

So the time complexity is `O((m+n)log(min(m,n))`

Comment: Please can you explain  how did you reach at it?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about how to derive it, but repeatedly traversing a list of increasing size is usually O(n log n)

Comment: But this worst case will never occur,right?(for which time complexity O(m+n+log(m+n)) holds true) as if there are maximum common elements  in both the lists then it will be worst case of linked list traversal ,on the other hand,if there are no common elements then it will be worst case for while loop so actual worst case can be within more tight bound.But still we can say that time taken will be less than this always.

Comment: @jane Well, that may be true, but I'd say that worst case is at least O(m log m) or something like that. That append operation will destroy any linearity.

Comment: Yeah,that's true.But can you check your time complexity once,it should be O(m+n+(m+n)log(m+n)) as you also said previously or that factor in front of log term will not depend on m or n?

Comment: O(m+n+(m+n)log(m+n)) = O((m+n)log(m+n)), but I do suspect you could narrow it down to something like O(m+n+(min(m,n)log(min(m,n)))

Comment: Yeah,last one seems fine O(m+n+(min(m,n)log(min(m,n)))  and I don't think it should be log(m+n) at all.What do you think?

Comment: Sounds reasonable. However, do remember that when talking about big O notation, it would not be wrong to say that this is O(m²+n²), since what you are actually saying with that is that it will never be worse than O(m²+n²). It's not a very good answer, but it's not wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure about the first min though. I think I'll settle at O((m+n)log(min(m,n)) cause I'm not sure it could be pushed lower.

Comment: No,but linked list traversal will happen only when a common element comes during traversal and the number of common elements can be atmost min(m,n).

Answer (score 0):

As in each iteration of `while`, at least one of the pointers go to the next, and the condition of `while` termination is none of the pointers reach to the end, the time complexity would be `O(min(m,n))`.

Answer (score 0):

In `worst case`  it will be `O(m+n)`

> `example: {1,3,5,7} {2,4,6,8}`
>    in this case you traverse both the
>   list.

In `average` case it will be

```
O(min(m,n) + number of times you don't increment the smaller list)
```

> `example :  {1,2,3,4,6} {2,4,6,8,9,10}`
>   in this case you terminate
>   the loop once you reach the end of first lined list but in between you
>   increment the second list without increment the first list.

In `best` case it will be `O(min(m,n))`

> `example: {1,2,3}  {1,2,3,4,}`
>   in this case you will terminate
>   the loop after reaching end of the first list.